# IBM Worklight 6.2.0.1 Application center - Android installation fail

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

I'm developing two applications on WL 6.2.0.1.

For Android when I'm using IBM application centre to install the app on my Android devices.

First App file size is 5MB and it is getting installed.

Second App file size is 9MB and it is not getting installed (Doesn't show the install overlay at all). The behaviour as the following:

1. Click Install
2. It shows loading indicator on the Icon for 1 sec.
3. The Install button got activated again and nothing happens.

Both apps are signed with exact key and uploaded with exact way. IF I side loaded the app, it works and get installed.

I also tried to enable the App centre logging on WAS, but the only option I have is (which I don't think it is the correct logging):

[image]

**EDIT**

Clicking Install for App1 Logs (successful installation):

```
[1/12/16 14:11:49:035 EST] 000000ce MobileService > MobileServices applicationStorageHandler for any secured resource ENTRY 30572
[1/12/16 14:11:49:035 EST] 000000ce ApplicationSt > ApplicationStorageService ApplicationStorageService ENTRY 30572 null false
[1/12/16 14:11:49:037 EST] 000000ce ApplicationSt > ApplicationStorageService __retrieve__ ENTRY uri=https://x.x.x.x/applicationcenter/service/application/storage/30572 securityContext=org.apache.wink.server.internal.contexts.SecurityContextImpl_-146742545 httpRequest={Loc=en_US, Locs=(en_US,), User=CN==*********,,OU=CDN,OU=MFC_Users,DC=americas,DC=company,DC=net, RemoteUser=CN==*********,,OU=CDN,OU=MFC_Users,DC=americas,DC=company,DC=net} null
[1/12/16 14:11:49:037 EST] 000000ce PrincipalHelp > PrincipalHelper getPrincipal ENTRY CN==*********,,OU=CDN,OU=MFC_Users,DC=americas,DC=company,DC=net
[1/12/16 14:11:49:037 EST] 000000ce PrincipalHelp > PrincipalHelper getPrincipalEntity ENTRY org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl@3eb5fcaf CN==*********,,OU=CDN,OU=MFC_Users,DC=americas,DC=company,DC=net
[1/12/16 14:11:49:041 EST] 000000ce ApplicationSt > BinaryStorageBaseService retrieveOrInfoImpl ENTRY uri=https://x.x.x.x/applicationcenter/service/application/storage/30572 securityContext=org.apache.wink.server.internal.contexts.SecurityContextImpl_-146742545 httpRequest={Loc=en_US, Locs=(en_US,), User=CN==*********,,OU=CDN,OU=MFC_Users,DC=americas,DC=company,DC=net, RemoteUser=CN=*********,OU=CDN,OU=MFC_Users,DC=americas,DC=company,DC=net}
[1/12/16 14:11:49:041 EST] 000000ce ApplicationSt 1 BinaryStorageBaseService retrieveOrInfoImpl Specified Range: bytes=unspec-unspec
[1/12/16 14:11:49:041 EST] 000000ce ApplicationRe > ApplicationResourceHelper getApplicationResource ENTRY 30572
[1/12/16 14:11:49:041 EST] 000000ce ApplicationRe > ApplicationResourceHelper findStorageRefEntity ENTRY 30572
[1/12/16 14:11:49:049 EST] 000000ce ApplicationRe > ApplicationResourceHelper getApplicationStorageEntity ENTRY 30523
[1/12/16 14:11:50:281 EST] 000000ce ApplicationSt 1 BinaryStorageBaseService retrieveOrInfoImpl Final Range: bytes=-1--1
[1/12/16 14:11:50:281 EST] 000000ce ApplicationSt < BinaryStorageBaseService retrieveOrInfoImpl RETURN org.apache.wink.common.internal.ResponseImpl@816f72ff
```

Installation Started:

```
[1/12/16 14:12:26:457 EST] 000000ce MobileService > MobileServices deviceHandler ENTRY
[1/12/16 14:12:26:461 EST] 000000ce SearchAndList > DeviceService applicationTracker ENTRY f8d88de1366f815c
[1/12/16 14:12:26:461 EST] 000000ce SearchAndList > InstallationTrackingService InstallationTrackingService ENTRY f8d88de1366f815c
[1/12/16 14:12:26:461 EST] 000000ce DeviceHelper  > DeviceHelper getDevice(deviceID) ENTRY f8d88de1366f815c
[1/12/16 14:12:26:462 EST] 000000ce DeviceHelper  > DeviceHelper findDevice(deviceID) ENTRY f8d88de1366f815c
[1/12/16 14:12:26:462 EST] 000000ce DeviceHelper  > DeviceHelper findDevice(deviceID,activeOnly) ENTRY f8d88de1366f815c true
[1/12/16 14:12:26:462 EST] 000000ce DeviceHelper  > DeviceHelper findDeviceEntity ENTRY f8d88de1366f815c true
[1/12/16 14:12:26:462 EST] 000000ce DeviceHelper  > DeviceHelper getDeviceEntities ENTRY f8d88de1366f815c true
[1/12/16 14:12:26:477 EST] 000000ce SearchAndList > InstallationTrackingService __create__ ENTRY uri=https://x.x.x.x/applicationcenter/service/device/f8d88de1366f815c/package securityContext=org.apache.wink.server.internal.contexts.SecurityContextImpl_-1579924706 {"pkg":"ca.company.App2","version":"1","to_update":"Y"}
[1/12/16 14:12:26:477 EST] 000000ce PrincipalHelp > PrincipalHelper getPrincipal ENTRY CN=*******,OU=CDN,OU=MFC_Users,DC=americas,DC=company,DC=net
[1/12/16 14:12:26:478 EST] 000000ce PrincipalHelp > PrincipalHelper getPrincipalEntity ENTRY org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl@567afade CN==*******,,OU=CDN,OU=MFC_Users,DC=americas,DC=company,DC=net
[1/12/16 14:12:26:481 EST] 000000ce SearchAndList > InstallationTrackingService create ENTRY {"to_update":"Y","pkg":"ca.company.MobileBanking","version":"1"} INSTALLED uri=https://10.205.44.97:443/applicationcenter/service/device/f8d88de1366f815c/package
[1/12/16 14:12:26:481 EST] 000000ce SearchAndList > InstallationTrackingService fromJsonObject ENTRY {"to_update":"Y","pkg":"ca.company.MobileBanking","version":"1"} INSTALLED
[1/12/16 14:12:26:481 EST] 000000ce DeviceHelper  > DeviceHelper getDevice(deviceID) ENTRY f8d88de1366f815c
[1/12/16 14:12:26:481 EST] 000000ce DeviceHelper  > DeviceHelper findDevice(deviceID) ENTRY f8d88de1366f815c
[1/12/16 14:12:26:481 EST] 000000ce DeviceHelper  > DeviceHelper findDevice(deviceID,activeOnly) ENTRY f8d88de1366f815c true
[1/12/16 14:12:26:481 EST] 000000ce DeviceHelper  > DeviceHelper findDeviceEntity ENTRY f8d88de1366f815c true
[1/12/16 14:12:26:481 EST] 000000ce DeviceHelper  > DeviceHelper getDeviceEntities ENTRY f8d88de1366f815c true
[1/12/16 14:12:26:485 EST] 000000ce ApplicationHe > ApplicationHelper getApplication ENTRY ca.company.MobileBanking@Android 1 true
[1/12/16 14:12:26:528 EST] 000000ce ApplicationHe > ApplicationHelper applicationInstalled ENTRY com.ibm.puremeap.artifacts.InstalledApplication@1052280d
[1/12/16 14:12:26:533 EST] 000000ce DeviceHelper  > DeviceHelper getDeviceEntity ENTRY com.ibm.puremeap.artifacts.Device@4a67fecb
[1/12/16 14:12:26:533 EST] 000000ce DeviceHelper  > DeviceHelper findDeviceEntity ENTRY f8d88de1366f815c false
[1/12/16 14:12:26:533 EST] 000000ce DeviceHelper  > DeviceHelper getDeviceEntities ENTRY f8d88de1366f815c false
[1/12/16 14:12:26:555 EST] 000000ce PureMeapBaseU 2   Found property ibm.appcenter.proxy.host=mobile-dev.company.ca in webapp context.
[1/12/16 14:12:26:556 EST] 000000ce PureMeapBaseU 2   Found property ibm.appcenter.proxy.port=443 in webapp context.
[1/12/16 14:12:26:556 EST] 000000ce PureMeapBaseU 2   Found property ibm.appcenter.proxy.protocol=https in webapp context.
[1/12/16 14:12:26:557 EST] 000000ce PureMeapBaseU 2   Found property ibm.appcenter.proxy.host=mobile-dev.company.ca in webapp context.
[1/12/16 14:12:26:558 EST] 000000ce PureMeapBaseU 2   Found property ibm.appcenter.proxy.port=443 in webapp context.
[1/12/16 14:12:26:558 EST] 000000ce PureMeapBaseU 2   Found property ibm.appcenter.proxy.protocol=https in webapp context.
[1/12/16 14:12:26:560 EST] 000000ce PureMeapBaseU 2   Found property ibm.appcenter.proxy.host=mobile-dev.company.ca in webapp context.
[1/12/16 14:12:26:561 EST] 000000ce PureMeapBaseU 2   Found property ibm.appcenter.proxy.port=443 in webapp context.
[1/12/16 14:12:26:562 EST] 000000ce PureMeapBaseU 2   Found property ibm.appcenter.proxy.protocol=https in webapp context.
[1/12/16 14:12:26:563 EST] 000000ce PureMeapBaseU 2   Found property ibm.appcenter.proxy.host=mobile-dev.company.ca in webapp context.
[1/12/16 14:12:26:564 EST] 000000ce PureMeapBaseU 2   Found property ibm.appcenter.proxy.port=443 in webapp context.
[1/12/16 14:12:26:565 EST] 000000ce PureMeapBaseU 2   Found property ibm.appcenter.proxy.protocol=https in webapp context.
[1/12/16 14:12:26:565 EST] 000000ce PureMeapBaseU 2   Found property ibm.appcenter.proxy.host=mobile-dev.company.ca in webapp context.
[1/12/16 14:12:26:566 EST] 000000ce PureMeapBaseU 2   Found property ibm.appcenter.proxy.port=443 in webapp context.
[1/12/16 14:12:26:566 EST] 000000ce PureMeapBaseU 2   Found property ibm.appcenter.proxy.protocol=https in webapp context.
[1/12/16 14:12:26:567 EST] 000000ce PureMeapBaseU 2   Found property ibm.appcenter.proxy.host=mobile-dev.company.ca in webapp context.
[1/12/16 14:12:26:568 EST] 000000ce PureMeapBaseU 2   Found property ibm.appcenter.proxy.port=443 in webapp context.
[1/12/16 14:12:26:568 EST] 000000ce PureMeapBaseU 2   Found property ibm.appcenter.proxy.protocol=https in webapp context.
[1/12/16 14:12:26:569 EST] 000000ce PureMeapBaseU 2   Found property ibm.appcenter.proxy.host=mobile-dev.company.ca in webapp context.
[1/12/16 14:12:26:570 EST] 000000ce PureMeapBaseU 2   Found property ibm.appcenter.proxy.port=443 in webapp context.
[1/12/16 14:12:26:571 EST] 000000ce PureMeapBaseU 2   Found property ibm.appcenter.proxy.protocol=https in webapp context.
[1/12/16 14:12:26:572 EST] 000000ce PureMeapBaseU 2   Found property ibm.appcenter.proxy.host=mobile-dev.company.ca in webapp context.
[1/12/16 14:12:26:572 EST] 000000ce PureMeapBaseU 2   Found property ibm.appcenter.proxy.port=443 in webapp context.
[1/12/16 14:12:26:573 EST] 000000ce PureMeapBaseU 2   Found property ibm.appcenter.proxy.protocol=https in webapp context.
[1/12/16 14:12:26:573 EST] 000000ce PureMeapBaseU 2   Found property ibm.appcenter.proxy.host=mobile-dev.company.ca in webapp context.
[1/12/16 14:12:26:574 EST] 000000ce PureMeapBaseU 2   Found property ibm.appcenter.proxy.port=443 in webapp context.
[1/12/16 14:12:26:575 EST] 000000ce PureMeapBaseU 2   Found property ibm.appcenter.proxy.protocol=https in webapp context.
[1/12/16 14:12:26:575 EST] 000000ce SearchAndList 3 InstallationTrackingService create Response: [{"avg_rating_all_versions":0.0,"avg_rating":0.0,"os":"Android","author_display":"uid=********,o=defaultWIMFileBasedRealm","link":"https:\/\/mobile-dev.company.ca:443\/applicationcenter\/service\/directory\/Android\/ca.company.MobileBanking\/1","to_update":"Y","nb_rating_all_versions":0.0,"pkg":"ca.company.MobileBanking","latest_version_link":"https:\/\/mobile-dev.company.ca:443\/applicationcenter\/service\/directory\/ca.company.MobileBanking@Android","label":"company Bank Mobile","versionName":"1.0","expkg":"ca.company.MobileBanking@Android","url":[{"id":"30572","link":"https:\/\/mobile-dev.company.ca:443\/applicationcenter\/service\/application\/storage\/30572","value":"application\/storage\/30572","filename":"MobileBanking-Android.apk","derived":"N","rel":"apk","cid":"30523","size":5276642},{"id":"30573","link":"https:\/\/mobile-dev.company.ca:443\/applicationcenter\/service\/icons\/application\/storage\/30573","value":"icons\/application\/storage\/30573","filename":"","derived":"Y","rel":"icon_hdpi","cid":"30524","size":8362},{"id":"30574","link":"https:\/\/mobile-dev.company.ca:443\/applicationcenter\/service\/icons\/application\/storage\/30574","value":"icons\/application\/storage\/30574","filename":"","derived":"Y","rel":"icon","cid":"30525","size":8362},{"id":"30575","link":"https:\/\/mobile-dev.company.ca:443\/applicationcenter\/service\/icons\/application\/storage\/30575","value":"icons\/application\/storage\/30575","filename":"","derived":"Y","rel":"icon_ldpi","cid":"30526","size":8362},{"id":"30576","link":"https:\/\/mobile-dev.company.ca:443\/applicationcenter\/service\/icons\/application\/storage\/30576","value":"icons\/application\/storage\/30576","filename":"","derived":"Y","rel":"icon_xhdpi","cid":"30527","size":8362},{"id":"30577","link":"https:\/\/mobile-dev.company.ca:443\/applicationcenter\/service\/icons\/application\/storage\/30577","value":"icons\/application\/storage\/30577","filename":"","derived":"Y","rel":"icon_mdpi","cid":"30528","size":8362}],"version":"1","versions":[{"is_rtw_instr":"N","is_active":"Y","updated":"2016-01-08T15:28:31.186Z","description":"Mobile Banking Android","link":"https:\/\/mobile-dev.company.ca:443\/applicationcenter\/service\/directory\/Android\/ca.company.MobileBanking\/1","is_ready_prod":"Y","label":"company Bank Mobile","versionName":"1.0","nb_rating":0.0,"version":"1"}],"author":"uid=********,o=defaultWIMFileBasedRealm","created":"2016-01-12T19:12:26.528Z","updated":"2016-01-12T19:12:26.528Z","description":"Mobile Banking Android","popularity_all_versions":26.0,"creation_time":1452625946528,"nb_rating":0.0,"popularity":26.0}]
```

App2 Click Installation (failed):

```
[1/12/16 14:04:13:554 EST] 000000cb MobileService > MobileServices applicationStorageHandler for any secured resource ENTRY 30681
[1/12/16 14:04:13:554 EST] 000000cb ApplicationSt > ApplicationStorageService ApplicationStorageService ENTRY 30681 null false
[1/12/16 14:04:13:556 EST] 000000cb ApplicationSt > ApplicationStorageService __retrieve__ ENTRY uri=https://x.x.x.x/applicationcenter/service/application/storage/30681 securityContext=org.apache.wink.server.internal.contexts.SecurityContextImpl_587347446 httpRequest={Loc=en_US, Locs=(en_US,), User=CN=xxxxxx,OU=CDN,OU=MFC_Users,DC=americas,DC=company,DC=net, RemoteUser=CN=xxxxxx,OU=CDN,OU=MFC_Users,DC=americas,DC=company,DC=net} null
[1/12/16 14:04:13:556 EST] 000000cb PrincipalHelp > PrincipalHelper getPrincipal ENTRY CN=xxxxxx,OU=CDN,OU=MFC_Users,DC=americas,DC=company,DC=net
[1/12/16 14:04:13:557 EST] 000000cb PrincipalHelp > PrincipalHelper getPrincipalEntity ENTRY org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl@fc7a7dd7 CN=xxxxxx,OU=CDN,OU=MFC_Users,DC=americas,DC=company,DC=net
[1/12/16 14:04:13:561 EST] 000000cb ApplicationSt > BinaryStorageBaseService retrieveOrInfoImpl ENTRY uri=https://x.x.x.x/applicationcenter/service/application/storage/30681 securityContext=org.apache.wink.server.internal.contexts.SecurityContextImpl_587347446 httpRequest={Loc=en_US, Locs=(en_US,), User=CN=xxxxxx,OU=CDN,OU=MFC_Users,DC=americas,DC=company,DC=net, RemoteUser=CN=xxxxxx,OU=CDN,OU=MFC_Users,DC=americas,DC=company,DC=net}
[1/12/16 14:04:13:561 EST] 000000cb ApplicationSt 1 BinaryStorageBaseService retrieveOrInfoImpl Specified Range: bytes=unspec-unspec
[1/12/16 14:04:13:561 EST] 000000cb ApplicationRe > ApplicationResourceHelper getApplicationResource ENTRY 30681
[1/12/16 14:04:13:561 EST] 000000cb ApplicationRe > ApplicationResourceHelper findStorageRefEntity ENTRY 30681
[1/12/16 14:04:13:570 EST] 000000cb ApplicationRe > ApplicationResourceHelper getApplicationStorageEntity ENTRY 30631
[1/12/16 14:04:15:193 EST] 000000cb ApplicationSt 1 BinaryStorageBaseService retrieveOrInfoImpl Final Range: bytes=-1--1
[1/12/16 14:04:15:193 EST] 000000cb ApplicationSt < BinaryStorageBaseService retrieveOrInfoImpl RETURN org.apache.wink.common.internal.ResponseImpl@9c51d90
```

**I don't see any difference between the two apps logs when I click "Install", just one of them is not getting started the installation process.**

1. Is there a file size download limit that I need to look at in the
   WAS configuration?
2. How can I troubleshoot the issue?
3. Is there a logging level that I need to add that WAS is not showing
   to me?

Any extra info required, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: There are no file size limitations.
Enable the following trace "com.ibm.puremeap.*=all"

Comment: Thank you Vivin, I updated my question with the logs.

Comment: What is the package id of the two applications ? I see "ca.company.MobileBanking". What is the other one?

Comment: We found out the reason at DataPower as we set the payload restriction to 8MB, which causing the installation to fail on the second app, it is also appeared on iPad as it has the same size. iPhone is working as the size is 7MB for the same app.

Comment: @HussamEddin please write the above as an answer to the  question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

After investigation, We found out the reason is at DataPower as we set the payload restriction to 8MB, which causing the installation to fail on the second app, it is also appeared on iPad as it has the same size.

DataPower Payload restriction : 8MB

Android apk size : 8.5MB (Failed to install through Datapower)

iPad ipa size : 8.4MB (Failed to install through Datapower)

iPhone ipa size : 7.4MB (success to install through Datapower)

If I tried to install internally by accessing our internal IHS server and bypass the DataPower, all installation works.

By increasing the payload restriction, we were able to fix our issue.